# Objective c - button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm new to Objective C. I have the following code :

```
UIButton *loginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, self.view.bounds.size.height-60, 230, 45)];
loginButton.backgroundColor =UIColorFromAltRGB(0xa40002);//RGB4(0xa40002);
loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:boldFontName size:14.0f];
[loginButton setTitle:@"CREATE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.5f] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createUser) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

whit :

```
-(void)createUser
{
    NSLog(@"create");
(....)
}
```

But it never show/log. Not entering the createuser.

**LE :**

if i put

```
  NSLog(@"he did load : %@",self.delegate);
```

it shows me the first screen. It suppose to show me the current viewcontroller ?

**LE :**

i resolve the problem by setting :

```
self.delegate = self
```

don't know why is working now... but it's ok... not my code
Thanks all for help

Comment: replace "UIControlEventTouchDown" with "UIControlEventTouchUpInside"

Comment: nope. still not working

Comment: your code working in my demo jst remove (....) from "-createUser" method

Comment: everything works fine for me in this code. So i think you should clean the project and restart xcode, try again. Probably it will work :)

Comment: Would need more code to clarify but you might have something like a transparent mask over your button or something? If you take this code and post it in a new project it will work fine.

Comment: i solved my problem. I edit my post whit my solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, I just verified it myself. Check that `self.view`'s frame is well configured. If it doesn't cover at the very least `loginButton.frame` then it won't be clickable.

Comment: It covers... i just set a bigger height and still not working

Comment: Perhaps there is another view on top of your UIButton that has `userInteractionEnabled = YES`?

Comment: It;s a code make from other coder. First it pops-up a view.... click a button ... popup my view with the buttom i'm talking about. So it's a secound view. I cand click the button... i think it is visible... i can interact whit him... but is not executing de click function

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me too. Another option is to verify you don't have a custom gesture recogniser attached to the entire view or its superview, if so, set this property in your gesture recogniser:

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: I can click the button and it take the hover style. But still not working

Answer (score 0):

change bound to frame, then you can console the create user

```
 UIButton *loginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, self.view.frame.size.height-60, 230, 45)];
    loginButton.backgroundColor =UIColorFromAltRGB(0xa40002);//RGB4(0xa40002);
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:boldFontName size:14.0f];
    [loginButton setTitle:@"CREATE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.5f] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createUser) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

Comment: Still not working.  In the same view i have one UISegmentControl and another TTSwitch. All are not responding to their action . No log in console. I can click them ... but no action.

Comment: If i put an action selector like "createUserasdad2312asdas" i get no error, no crash

Comment: can you put all your code here so that i can understand exactly.
for above code am getting response in console...

Comment: i solved my problem. I edit my post whit my solution. Thanks !